# Warning as Error: Possible unintended reference comparison when upgrading from .Net 3.5 to .Net 4.5

Tags: c#, reference, .net-3.5, comparison, .net-4.5

Currently I am in the process of migrating a WPF application from .Net Framework 3.5 to .Net Framework 4.5. Next to the upgrade of the .Net Framework, the application will now be compiled 64-bits instead of 32-bits. I get the following error when compiling the application:

*Warning as Error: Possible unintended reference comparison; to get a value comparison, cast the left hand side to type 'System.Type'*

My question is: why does this error occur now that I have upgraded to .Net 4.5 and never before on .Net 3.5?
I have not made any changes to the build properties of the project, both have the setting `Treat warnings as errors` set to `All`. Below is the code that produces the error, I have added some comments about the changes that I have made, the uncommented part compiles under .Net 4.5.

```
private void FoldersListBoxMouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    // Get typed sender
    ListBox typedSender = sender as ListBox;
    if (typedSender != null)
    {
        // Check if an item was double clicked
        //The line below worked in .Net 3.5, but not in .Net 4.5
        //if ((typedSender.SelectedItem != null) && (typedSender.InputHitTest(e.GetPosition(typedSender)) != typedSender.GetType()))
        //And this is the line that I have changed (I added GetType()!).
        if ((typedSender.SelectedItem != null) && (typedSender.InputHitTest(e.GetPosition(typedSender)).GetType() != typedSender.GetType()))
        {
            // Yes, set the new path
            SelectedPath = typedSender.SelectedValue as string;
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: I have looked up when this code was added to the application, but was unable to go find it, because the Subversion repository only goes back 6 years.

Comment: Can you explain what this condition is checking (as you think?). [InputHitTest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.inputhittest.aspx) returns `IInputElement`, what is the logic behind when comparing it to `typeof(ListBox`) ? To *double-ensure*? =D

Comment: This error is available [since 2003](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f6dtw2ah(v=vs.71).aspx) (im assuming this is even from previous c-sharp compilers). Are you sure you're simply not ignoring it somehow?

Comment: @Sinatr: My guess would be that the original programmer is checking to see if the user has actually double-clicked on an item in the ListBox and not on for example a scrollbar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your previous code was broken, basically. You say it worked, but I can't see that the condition would ever be false. I suspect the compiler is just smarter now than it was before. The condition was:

```
typedSender.InputHitTest(e.GetPosition(typedSender)) != typedSender.GetType()
```

Now `InputHitTest` returns a value of type `IInputElement`. So the condition (ignoring the first part) can be rewritten as:

```
IInputElement element = typedSender.InputHitTest(e.GetPosition(typedSender));
Type type = typedSender.GetType();
if (element != type)
{
    ...
}
```

The *only* way in which the two references could be equal would be if they were both `null`, and `typedSender.GetType()` will never return `null`, so the condition is pointless.

You're *now* comparing whether the input element which is the result of the hit test is of the same type as `typedSender`, which at least makes sense - although it doesn't check that it *is* `typedSender`.

It's worth noting that the [documentation for `InputHitTest`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.inputhittest) includes:

> This method typically is not called from your application code. Calling this method is only appropriate if you intend to re-implement a substantial amount of the low level input features that are already present, such as recreating mouse device logic.

Are you *sure* you want to call it?

Comment: Wild guess: it's someone signature (something what doesn't impact functionality, hard to detect and can be used to catch source pirates).

Comment: @Sinatr: The code is more than 6 years old and it can not be traced who wrote it, but judging by the rest of the application I would say it is simply a mistake and not a cunning plan to catch source pirates.

Comment: So, the code was broken to begin with and now I have 'fixed' it, but that will mean that the application will respond different from what it used to do... Futhermore, I am not sure what problem this code is suppose to fix. So, am I sure I want to call this code? No, it think I will just remove it and add a link to this answer in the comments.

Comment: @GeertImmerzeel: Well to restore the original behaviour, just take out the condition entirely. The condition always evaluated to `true`, because the references were always different.

Comment: @JonSkeet: that was what I intended to do.